# How to draw PDF including multiple records in iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, ios7, quartz-core

I am working on PDF generation functionality below functionality working fine in iOS 6 but not working in iOS7, so please help me regarding same issue.

```
 (float) drawText:(NSString *)body currentVehical:(NSInteger)currentVehical{

    CGContextRef    currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(currentContext, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];

    NSLog(@" FRame : \n%f\n%f",(self.pageSize.width - 2*kBorderInset-2*kMarginInset),
```

(self.pageSize.height - 2*kBorderInset - 2*kMarginInset));

```
    CGSize stringSize = [body sizeWithFont:font
                         constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(self.pageSize.width - 2*kBorderInset-2*kMarginInset, self.pageSize.height - 2*kBorderInset - 2*kMarginInset)
                             lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];


    CGRect renderingRect = CGRectMake(120,10+self.yCord, self.pageSize.width - 120,stringSize.height+KExtraSpaces);

    NSLog(@"PDF draw rect: %@",NSStringFromCGRect(renderingRect));

    if (IS_IOS7) {
        NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphstyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
        paragraphstyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        paragraphstyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        NSDictionary * attributes = @{ NSFontAttributeName:font, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphstyle };
            //[body drawInRect:renderingRect withAttributes:attributes];
        NSStringDrawingContext *context = [NSStringDrawingContext new];
        context.minimumScaleFactor = 0.1;
        NSLog(@"body :%@",body);
        [body drawWithRect:renderingRect options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:attributes context:context];
    }else{

    [body drawInRect:renderingRect withFont:font lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping alignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
    }
    return stringSize.height;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I want simple code or solution to draw the PDF with text. please suggest if you have any solution, I don't have problem related iOS6. Only facing problem in iOS7.

Answer (score 0):

I recall having a similar problem with a pdf renderer when compiling for iOS7, when it worked perfectly for ios6.1. I seem to remember that the font size was the issue, debug your routine and check font sizes and subsequent frame sizes. Apologies that I can't be more specific, as solved it 3 months ago and forgotten.

Hope this code helps:

```
+(void)drawTableDataAt:(Survey*)survey columns:(NSMutableArray*)savedColumns listContent:(NSArray*)surveyListContent withOrigin:(CGPoint)origin andRowCount:(int*)count andMaxRowOnPage:(int)size andLinesPerPage:(int)linesPerPage andColumnWidths:(NSMutableArray*)columnWidths withFont:(UIFont*)theFont withLabelFont:(UIFont*)theLabelFont
{
float rowHeight = theFont.lineHeight+3.0;
float padding = -5.0f;

// ………..

CGRect frame = CGRectMake(originX + padding, originY, [[columnWidths objectAtIndex:j] integerValue], rowHeight);
[self drawText:strValue inFrame:frame withFont:theFont   withAlignment:kCTRightTextAlignment];

// ………..
}

+(void)drawText:(NSString*)textToDraw inFrame:(CGRect)frameRect withFont:(UIFont*)theFont withAlignment:(CTTextAlignment)textAlignment
{

CFStringRef stringRef = (__bridge_retained CFStringRef)textToDraw;
NSString *fontName = [theFont fontName];
CGFloat fontSize = [theFont pointSize];
// Set Font
CTFontRef font = CTFontCreateWithName( (__bridge CFStringRef)fontName, fontSize, NULL);
CTParagraphStyleSetting settings[ASD_ParagraphStylesSupported];

settings[0].spec = kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierAlignment;
settings[0].valueSize = sizeof(CTTextAlignment);
settings[0].value = &textAlignment;

CTParagraphStyleRef style = CTParagraphStyleCreate((const CTParagraphStyleSetting*) &settings, ASD_ParagraphStylesSupported);

// Create an attributed string
CFStringRef keys[] = { kCTFontAttributeName, kCTForegroundColorAttributeName, kCTParagraphStyleAttributeName };
CFTypeRef values[] = { font, [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor], style };
CFDictionaryRef attrs = CFDictionaryCreate(NULL, (const void **)&keys, (const void **)&values,
                                           sizeof(keys) / sizeof(keys[0]), &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks, &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);
// Prepare the text using a Core Text Framesetter with Attributes
CFAttributedStringRef currentText = CFAttributedStringCreate(NULL, stringRef, attrs);

CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(currentText);


CGMutablePathRef framePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddRect(framePath, NULL, frameRect);

// Get the frame that will do the rendering.
CFRange currentRange = CFRangeMake(0, 0);
CTFrameRef frameRef = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter, currentRange, framePath, NULL);
CGPathRelease(framePath);

// Get the graphics context.
CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

// Put the text matrix into a known state. This ensures
// that no old scaling factors are left in place.
CGContextSetTextMatrix(currentContext, CGAffineTransformIdentity);


// Core Text draws from the bottom-left corner up, so flip
// the current transform prior to drawing.
CGContextTranslateCTM(currentContext, 0, frameRect.origin.y*2);
CGContextScaleCTM(currentContext, 1.0, -1.0);

// Draw the frame.
CTFrameDraw(frameRef, currentContext);

CGContextScaleCTM(currentContext, 1.0, -1.0);
CGContextTranslateCTM(currentContext, 0, (-1)*frameRect.origin.y*2);

CFRelease(settings);
CFRelease(attrs);
CFRelease(style);
CFRelease(font);
CFRelease(frameRef);
CFRelease(stringRef);
CFRelease(framesetter);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable feedback on my question.